# How to check if the item already in collection

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to automate some website : https://www.pexels.com/

Before I add the item to collection i need to check if it already exist in collection.
If it's not exist , only then I need to add it.

The problem is that the use some svg icons for collection that the selected item appears in.

So how can i check this ?

Here is my code

```
public class test {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static JavascriptExecutor js;
    private static Actions action;

    private String COLLECTION = "TestCollection";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/michaelionia/Downloads/chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        opt.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222 ");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        action = new Actions(driver);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.pexels.com/search/videos/skyline/?orientation=landscape&size=large");
    }

    @Test
    public void openBrowser() {
        for (int j = 1; j < 200; j++) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                try {
                    WebElement preview = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[6]/div[1]/div[" + i + "]/div[" + j + "]/article"));
                    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", preview);
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(preview)).click();
                    WebElement collectButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"photo-page-top\"]/div/div[2]/div/div/button[2]"));

                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(collectButton)).click();

                    for (int k = 1; k < 200; k++) {
                        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[" + k + "]")).getText().equals(COLLECTION)) {
                            try {
                                WebElement collection = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[" + k + "]"));
                                collection.click();
                                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
                                new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"photo-modal\"]/div[2]/button")))).click();
                            } catch (ElementClickInterceptedException e) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is collection with the V icon.

[image]

And without V icon.

[image]

Comment: I can't see where in your code you are trying to add object to a collection.

Comment: Hi @Prophet ,

Here: 
WebElement collection = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[" + k + "]"));
                                collection.click();

Comment: yes where is collection ? Did you mean `WebElement collection` ? but you can't add into a webelement

Comment: @cruisepandey,
The item added to collection when I clicking on the collection.

All I need is to check if the item already is in collection.

If the collection contain the green overlay with the V icon, so the item already here

Comment: So you defined the question no clear enough

Comment: @Prophet 

The script is working well, and the items are added to collection.

The problem is when i clicking on collection the already contain this item , the item is removed from the collection =]]].

Comment: there is a collection framework in Java. that gives you list, set, queue and map interface.

Comment: @cruisepandey, All I need is to check if the V icon or the green overlay is appears on the collection , that's all.

Comment: Correct, but you didn't explain this in the question

Comment: @Prophet, ohh sry, but can you help me with the issue?

Comment: Can you help us with V icon or green overlay HTML code ?

Comment: variable name collection is confusing

Comment: With a pleasure, but I still don't see how to have the screen like on your question to see the elements with V and without to see the difference between them

Comment: @Prophet, You need to be logged in to see.

I will update the post with the image of the collection without icon

Comment: @Prophet Updated, please check

Comment: @Michael : I have signed up to the website. Please tell me navigation steps to reach destination

Comment: @cruisepandey https://www.pexels.com/search/videos/skyline/?orientation=landscape&size=large

Comment: I would suggest you to go to your collection menu first then scrape items from there and store them in a list and now that list will represent actual items of your collection then when you are adding a new item into it, you can have a check whtr to add or not. Does it make sense to you ?